# How would I get all the reqs of a requirements.txt file using pip to someone with blocked internet access?

Tags: python, pip

I'm basically trying to get a Python app going in my office for taking care of a task, but one of the requirements doesn't play well right now with pybundle and for some reason that doesn't seem to install correctly on their machine.

Are there any other easy options to get all the requirements to other people?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found my own answer.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -d ./path/to/desired_package_dir
```

This downloads all the packages as is, which are all .tar.gz. And then in my instance, the packages are shared via version control. Then the other person can install all the packages in the directory by:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --download-cache=./path/to/desired_package_dir
```

Haven't 100% confirmed this but I think it will be successful...

Answer (score 0):

Not tried it ever, but isn't that what the `pip bundle` command is for?  From looking at the output of `pip help bundle` it looks like it'll even take an input file containing the list of packages.  Having never used it, not sure just what it is that it produces.

I think the idea is that you'd run pip bundle on a system that's the same as the target machine (os and such) but which is connected, then transfer the bundle made by it to the unconnected machine.

Comment: I tried using this method but it seemed to file for some requirements because it wasn't able to access the internet. I'm in the process of retrying just in case something trivial occurred but also looking for another option.